# Passing quotes within quotes in a BATCH file

Tags: batch-file, grasshopper, rhino3d

I have been looking around for a solution to this one, but so far I have been unsuccessful. I am trying to open two programs using a batch file. The problem is that both of the paths to these files contain spaces, and one of these paths is already enclosed in quotation marks. Because of the the second file (.gh file) does not open. I have already tried putting the second path in quotation marks, and using the `\` character to escape the quotation marks, but without any result. Any help is appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Users\\Google Drive\Rhino Werk\MT1458\WIP
"C:\Program Files\Rhino 6\System\Rhino.exe" /nosplash /runscript="-grasshopper editor load document open C:\Users\<username>\Google Drive\Rhino Werk\MT1458\WIP\MT1458_HullGenerator_V2.64_NAKIJKMODEL.gh _enter" "C:\Users\<username>\Google Drive\Rhino Werk\MT1458\WIP\MT1458_HullGenerator_V2.59_001.3dm"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d "C:\Users\\Google Drive\Rhino Werk\MT1458\WIP"
"C:\Program Files\Rhino 6\System\Rhino.exe" /nosplash /runscript="-grasshopper editor load document open \"%userprofile%\Google Drive\Rhino Werk\MT1458\WIP\MT1458_HullGenerator_V2.64_NAKIJKMODEL.gh\" _enter \"%userprofile%\Google Drive\Rhino Werk\MT1458\WIP\MT1458_HullGenerator_V2.59_001.3dm\""
```

This would be following C++ argv rules of escaping inner double quotes with a backslash. Whether this works or not is unknown as I do not have or use Rhino.